# How to parse session url from one store to another in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, login, redirect, multidomain

I have two stores.
Store A - Showing products as a catalog, unable to buy.
Store B - Able to buy for exclusive customers with a given login account.

That I want to do is, create a button on store A at product page called "Login and order". Clicking on this button will redirect the user to store B. Store B is configured in the way, that users can only access it if login.
Code for the URL link in view.phtml in Store A's template:

```
<?php
    $shopProId = $_product->getId();
    $shopProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(4)->load($shopProId)->getProductUrl();
?>
<a href="<?php echo $shopProduct; ?>">bestil</a>
```

The url of the link looks like this: https://storeA.com/category/productname?SID=123456789&_storetitle

After clicking on the link, it will redirect the user to Store B and asked the user to login. The URL for the login page looks like this: https://storeB.com/customer/account/login/

But the problem is, the session was never passed, or it could maybe not be done like this. So after logging in, the website just redirected me to account dashboard. I also have change the status to "No" on `System->Configuration->Customer->Customer Configuration > Login Options`

I'm thinking this could maybe be done if modify the loginPostRedirect() function in AccountController.php?
But I have no idea how? Anyone have an example of how to do it?